# How can I remove a clickable bar with hyperlink in each page of a pdf file?

Tags: pdf

Can we remove a long narrow clickable bar(with some hidden text and link) at the bottom of each page of [this pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/new2.pdf)? When never I click it, it will tries to open a website in my browser.

I prefer to do that from command line, because there may be a pdf file with more pages with such bars.

I tried https://superuser.com/a/536644/9265, but it only can remove the text in the bar, and the bar and the hyperlink still exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171853/how-can-i-remove-a-clickable-bar-with-hyperlink-in-each-page-of-a-pdf-file) questions across multiple sites at once, it's considered rude. It's ok this time but please don't do it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removing Links

You can remove embedded links (inserted by authoring applications or by Acrobat). Here’s how to do so in Acrobat X or XI:

Choose Tools > Document Processing > Remove All Links

Comment: I am looking for Ubuntu solution... esp. command line solution.